# What is complexity of O(1/n) compared to O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, timing

Is O(1/n) faster growing than O(1)? I am studying time complexity and saw O(1/n) being compared to O(n) as one of my exercise questions, and I had never seen that before. Not sure how to deduce the answer to this question.

Comment: Calculate the value of 1/n for increasing values of n. Does it grow faster than a series of 1s?

Comment: Also think about the upper bound of `O(1/n)` for `n in N`.

Answer (score 2):

A complexity of `O(1/n)` would means that the more data you process, the faster is the algorithm... Quite difficult to believe, for first, and second let's do maths: the limit of 1/x when x goes to +INF is **zero**...

The algorithm would resolve instantly the problem, then? Hey, let's forget about quantum computing, we found something better! :)

Stop joking: such a complexity doesn't exist. Because `1/n` is a **decreasing** monotonic function. Complexities are ***increasing monotonic functions*** - at best, it's `O(1)`, meaning a constant time whatever the data quantity is. It's not even a so common complexity for an algorithm, in fact, even if it's quite frequent for certain operations / manipulations.

For example, retrieving the head of a standard linked list is indeed `O(1)`, even if the list is empty or if it contains all possible data of Universe (if it was storable...), because list's head is what is stored to access it. It's the same for all operations involving only exchanging pointers/handles exclusively, all direct accesses (like the `[]` operator of most arrays), etc. but most algorithms don't have such a nice complexity.

But even a simple (deep) copy is `O(n)`... Most researchs in a storage are in `O(log2(n))`. Most sorts are in `O(n.log2(n))`. Most cross-comparisons are in `O(n²)`. All these functions are (strictly) increasing. All these functions tend to infinity when n also tends to infinity.

Comment: "is i in the set S?" is trivially true when the size of S reaches infinity :-)

Comment: @tgdavies Buy me the RAM to store data, I need to test... ;)

Comment: This is certainly true, but big-O notation doesn't have to be used *only* for time complexity, and there may be other contexts where O(1/n) would make sense. For example, I could imagine there being a statistical algorithm whose the expected error is inversely proportional to the number of samples.

Comment: @ruakh You're mixing up things. `O()` notations aren't for the result correctness/accuracy of an algorithm, neither for the execution time itself in fact, but for the **number of operations to finish the algorithm** and reaching its end - proved formally. On our usual machines (both Harvard and von Neumann architectures), there is a direct correlation between execution time and number of operations. So your statistical algorithm MAY be way more precise with an increasing number of data (your 1/n), but its complexity will still be `O(n)` (average) to `O(n²)` and more (cross-references).

Comment: @Wisblade: It's you who are mixing things up. [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) describes the behavior of a mathematical function. It's *most often* used for measures of algorithmic complexity, such as the number of operations or memory cells or storage locations required by an algorithm; but it's 100% valid to use this notation to characterize any other kind of function where it's useful to do so.

Comment: @ruakh Nobody never use `O()` notations for algorithms for anything else but their complexity. OP speaks about complexity, too. Nobody uses `O()` for accuracy - even memory usage is very rarely characterized with `O()`, unless it starts to be a big problem - and it's then near always put with the complexity tradeoff it implies, like "algo is `O(n²)` with `O(n)` RAM usage, can go to `O(log2(n))` at the cost of `O(n²)` memory". It _**MAY**_ be valid, but NOBODY uses it. Accuracy/precision is given with something else, for example "10e-10 precision guaranteed" or "error rate is 10e-6".

Comment: @ruakh Don't forget: we don't speak here about mathematics, but about computer sciences and analysis of algorithms. Not for other usages, or bordeline ones. As I said, using `O()` for anything else than complexity is when something else (memory usage, number of transactions/seeks on a mass storage, etc.) become critical not for the algorithm itself, but for the execution time. For your first example, expected error is usually very well known, and usually you'll hit CPU/FPU precision limits before you'll hit algorithm's inherent precision, with huge data... Invalidating any `O()` on it.